# Hyperledger Composer BNA deployment results in timeout

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I've successfully deployed a bna on the provided `hlfv1` network by Composer. I now want to deploy it on my own network. I've followed the tutorial "Build your first network" for Hyperledger Fabric and added a CA. Now, when trying to deploy a BNA with composer, using `composer network deploy -a maintenance-network.bna -p maintenance -i PeerAdmin -s randomString -A admin -S`, i get an error:

```
Error: Error trying deploy. Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: Timeout expired while starting chaincode maintenance-network:0.14.2(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.org1.example.com,tx:a2ee7c864d656d01315f128ba9c028d5059ef2f9e008f97d2c1ad11fbd6b1013)
Command failed
```

Does anyone know what causes the error ?

This is the output of `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
b8cf89d35ba5        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:10051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10053->7053/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
492a09998560        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                             orderer.example.com
d25c64b188d1        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp     peer1.org1.example.com
2e64ba87132e        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp     peer0.org1.example.com
55a23706aaf8        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:9051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->7053/tcp     peer0.org2.example.com
f719beb58fb9        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                             ca_peerOrg1
```

This is my `connection.json`:

```
{
"type": "hlfv1",
"name": "maintenance",
"orderers": [
   { "url" : "grpc://localhost:7050" }
],
"ca": { "url": "http://localhost:7054",
        "name": "ca-org1" 
},
"peers": [
        {
            "requestURL": "grpc://localhost:7051",
            "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:7053"
        },
        {
            "requestURL": "grpc://localhost:8051",
            "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:8053"
        }
],
"keyValStore": "/home/vagrant/.composer-credentials",
"channel": "mychannel",
"mspID": "Org1MSP",
"timeout": "1000"
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Composer v0.14.2.  Please tell me if you need any more information or files.

Answer (score 0):

have you actually done a `composer runtime install` on the new peers you have added? Needs to be done on each peer.  This installs the Composer runtime code on the peers, in preparation for the business network you will plan to subsequently deploy using `composer network start` (where it tries to start the business network on the peers you configured in your connection profile). That said, I don't know how your connection profile has been set up (ie this being pre v0.15.0 version of Composer, where business network cards are used instead of `-p <connectionprofilename>` parameter in pre-0.15.0 versions)

Comment: Was the `composer runtime install` required in `v0.14.2` ? 
I've just executed `composer runtime install -n maintenance-network -p maintenance -i PeerAdmin` successfully. However, `composer network deploy -a ~/maintenance-network/dist/maintenance-network.bna -p maintenance -i PeerAdmin -s randomString -A admin -S` still fails with the error mentioned above. 
I've added the connection.json to my question. 

Updating to `v.0.15.0` is not possible at the moment.

Comment: you will need to enable full logging in the peer to see what is happening in the peer itself. Also if you are building a fabric yourself make sure you are using 1.0.x versions of fabric and not compiling from master/release1.1 or using the tech preview of fabric 1.1

Answer (score 0):

I've now updated to `Composer v0.15.1`, and followed the tutorial at https://sstone1.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html . Thanks for the help.